# Get element of HashSet<T> by position

Tags: c#, hashset

Is there a way to grab the third row from a `HashSet`?  Like

```
HashSet<string> ContinuedForums = new HashSet<string>();
ContinuedForums.add("a");
ContinuedForums.add("b");
string hellow = ContinuedForums[1];
```

Yes I want to use a `HashSet`.

Comment: Sure. Enumerate and grab the first two, discard them. Then grab the third and exit the loop. This could be done also using Linq `.Skip(2).First()`. If you want a better method, use a better tool. Also note that enumeration order and insertion order are not guaranteed to match.

Comment: var value = ContinuedForums.ToList()[2];
:)

Comment: Prev comment more efficient though!

Comment: look this http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kaltofen/courses/Languages/JavaExamples/jgl3.1.0/doc/api/com.objectspace.jgl.examples.HashSetExamples.html

Comment: this looks like a misuse of the datastructure too me

Comment: You may not get correct results is b was added before a

Comment: "third" by what critera? Third one added? Third one by sorted value? "Third" has no real meaning to a HashSet.

Comment: I've updated title - feel free to revert/improve.

Comment: As an example, in many versions of .NET, if you first add `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`, then remove `"b"`, and finally add `"d"`, then the members are yielded in the order `"a"`, `"d"`, `"c"` when you `foreach`. However that could change, in principle, in future versions of .NET.

Answer (score 16):

A `HashSet<T>` is by its nature *unordered*.

You can grab the third element via `ContinuedForums.Skip(2).First()`, but this won't necessarily be the "third" element you added, and the ordering will change as you add or remove elements.

If you need to preserve the order, then a `HashSet<T>` is likely the wrong collection type to use.  It is not intended to preserve order or access by index.

Comment: +1. [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) maybe the data structure to use instead.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Perhaps, or just a HashSet + List, etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to balance the order with performance, you're likely better off keeping two structures... The HashSet<T> for O(1) lookups and a List<T> for enumeration (or quick index accessor lookup).

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about "third" in the context of third one added, then there is no way. That information is not exposed by HashSet. It is an undocumented side effect of the internal implementation of HashSet that if you add these strings to a HashSet: "one", "two", "three", you will get the contents back in the same order they were added if you enumerate over its contents. But since this is undocumented behavior, it would be a big mistake to write code that depends on that behavior. The reason is that future versions of HashSet may behave in an entirely different way. Also note that if you were to remove "two" from the HashSet, and then add "four", enumerating over the HashSet will likely then return "one", "four", "three".

The whole notion of "Position" is an internal implementation detail of HashSet. It exposes nothing in its methods and properties that makes any promise of providing information about position. So, as far as users of HashSet are concerned, the concept of position does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If the order in the set is important you may use [SortedSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx).

This won't give you items in the order in which you added them, it will sort them instead.

Comment: MSDN links **do** die very often. However, the contents of the link don't really answer the question any more than the text here does. @FoundWaldoException: Including a code sample which does what the OP needs with your recommended library would be an excellent answer.